# What logical condition can I use to skip lines in the logic for f = .8 and f = .4?

Tags: c, logic, cs50

First of all, this question may take you 15-20 minutes to understand. I'm writing a program called **resize** which resizes given images. Assume the table below as a 6x6px 24bit bmp image in which 0-35 represent 36 pixels.

```
row
 1| 0  1  2  3  4  5

 2| 6  7  8  9  10 11

 3| 12 13 14 15 16 17

 4| 18 19 20 21 22 23

 5| 24 25 26 27 28 29

 6| 30 31 32 33 34 35
```

Now I've a staff program to play with (not source, just binary) which produce the following output image (staff.bmp) for `f = 0.8`, `f = 0.5` and `f = 0.4` respectively.

```
$ ~cs50/hacker4/resize 0.8 test6x6.bmp staff.bmp
f = 0.8
----------
0-3| 12 13 14 15
1-4| 18 19 20 21
2-5| 24 25 26 27
3-6| 30 31 32 33
```

My understanding of the logic for f = 0.8 is as follows: here 6 is the input file's height, and 4 is the output file's height as `floor(6 * 0.8) = 4.8 = 4 (floored down)`

```
Logic: 
6 in rows = 4 out rows
in/out rows = 6/4 = 1.5 
current = 0 + 1.5 = 1.5 = 1 #skip

5 in rows = 4 out rows
in/out rows = 5 / 4 = 1.25
current = 1 + 1.25 = 2.25 = 2 #skip

4 in rows = 4 out rows
in/out rows = 4/4  = 1
current = 2 + 1 = 3

3 in rows  =  3 out rows
in/out rows = 3/3 = 1
current = 3 + 1 = 4

2 in rows = 2 out rows 
in/out rows = 2/2 = 1
current = 4 + 1 = 5

1 in rows = 1 out rows 
in/out rows = 1/1 = 1
current = 5 + 1 = 6
```

For f = 0.5:

```
$ ~cs50/hacker4/resize 0.5 test6x6.bmp staff.bmp
f = 0.5
----------
0-2| 6  8  10

1-4| 18 20 22

2-6| 30 32 34

Logic:
6 in rows = 3 out rows
in/out rows = 6/3 = 2
current = 0 + 2 = 2

4 in rows = 2 out rows
in/out rows = 4/2 = 2
current = 2 + 2 = 4

2 in rows = 1 out row
in/out rows = 2/1  = 2
current = 4 + 2 = 6
```

Finally, for f = 0.4:

```
$ ~cs50/hacker4/resize 0.4 test6x6.bmp staff.bmp
f = 0.4
-------
0-4| 18 20
1-6| 30 32

Logic:
6 in rows = 2 out rows
in/out rows = 6/2  =  3
current = 0  + 3  =  3 #skip

3 in rows = 2 out rows 
in/out rows = 3/2 = 1.5
current = 3 + 1.5 = 4.5 = 4

2 in rows = 1 out rows 
in/out rows = 2/1 = 2 
current = 4 + 2  = 6
```

I wrote this program which resize image successfully when f is greater than 1. For example: if f is 2 than it will convert a 6x6px image to a 12x12px image.

```
/**
 * Resizes a BMP piece by piece, just because.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize f infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // convert string argument to float
    float f;
    sscanf(argv[1], " %f", &f);

    if(f > 100.0 || f < 0.0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./resize f infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];

    // open input file 
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 1;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 1;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf, bfOut;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bfOut = bf;

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi, biOut;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    biOut = bi;

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    //update BITMAPINFOHEADER for new resized file
    biOut.biWidth = floor(bi.biWidth * f);
    biOut.biHeight = floor(bi.biHeight * f);

    // determine padding for output file's scanline
    int paddingOut = (4 - biOut.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) % 4) % 4;

    // calculate output file image size header
    biOut.biSizeImage = ((sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * biOut.biWidth) + paddingOut) * abs(biOut.biHeight);

    //update BITMAPFILEHEADER for new resized file
    bfOut.bfSize = biOut.biSizeImage + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bfOut, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&biOut, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    //create array in memory for storing scanline of inFile.width elements
    RGBTRIPLE *scanLine = (RGBTRIPLE *) malloc(sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * bi.biWidth);


    // Iterate over inFile's scanlines one by one.
    int inRows =  abs(bi.biHeight), outRows = abs(biOut.biHeight), current = 0;

    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        // iterate over pixels and store them in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);

            // write RGB triple to scanline
            scanLine[j] = triple;
        }

        if(f< 1.0) {
            current += inRows/outRows;
            inRows -= floor(inRows/outRows);
            printf("%i\n", current);
            //***todo****
            //if(condition)
            //  continue;
            outRows--; 
        }

        //write scanline and padding to file n times verticlly 
        int ind;
        for(int m = 0;  m < ceil(f); m++) {

            //scanline
            for(int l = 0; l < biOut.biWidth; l++) {
                ind = l/f;
                fwrite(&scanLine[ind], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }

            //padding
            for(int o = 0; o < paddingOut; o++) 
                fputc(0x00, outptr);

        }

        // skip over padding, if any
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    // cleanup
    free(scanLine);
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);

    // success
    return 0;
}
```

What condition on line 118 (under todo section) will successfully #skip lines(as in logic) for f = 0.8 (first two lines to be skipped), f = 0.5 (no lines to be skipped) and f = 0.4 (only first line to be skipped)?

If you still don't understand the problem, here is the [full explanation](http://docs.cs50.net/problems/resize/more/resize.html).

Comment: Why do you think for f = 0.5 that you don't have to skip any lines? Surely you have to skip every alternate line to go from 6 to 3 lines.

Comment: because image height is 6. `6 * 0.5 = 3` so 3 is output image height. Logic starts from row number 2 as `6/3 = 2`.

Comment: @ChrisTurner, edited question by adding this explanation before logic for f = .8. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started debugging here right, it seems, by trying the integer values first. But, before you go to cropping images, it might be better if you make sure this program works as intended for enlarging images by a `float` factor, which looks like you didn't do. So go on and try values like `1.5`, `1.9` and `2.1` for your 6x6px image and also CS50's 3x3px `small.bmp`.

If you tried it and got some strange results (like resizing `small.bmp` by 2.1 resulting in a 6x7px image, with the upper border 3px and the lower just 1px), then I am afraid that just adding some code in the `todo` section won't be enough. Your resizing algorithm seems to be fully functional just for integers, but you, as a challenger, wants to do the 'more comfortable' way. So I really recommend that you redo your resizing algorithm, focusing solely on `float` implementation since it is the broader case here.

I am sorry if this wasn't what you expected, but if you need more help, I'll be pleasured to do so.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ganganimaulik/2d0a194367b192a5c3ce19e6048a511c 

now I will try this (line 82-84), I will also need to take care of top-down and bottom-up DIB.